# HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID equivalent for .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm building a webservice using **.NET 6** and I need an (almost) **constant ID** identifying my application.
I was thinking about using  `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID` but it seems to not be available for **.NET 6**.
What is the equivalent of this property for .NET 6 ?

Comment: How constant? A single value that never changes? A value that can be configured per-installation...?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman : Either options. I need a value to identify this application. It must be constant between two execution in case of reboot, for example.

Comment: DataProtectionUtilityExtensions.GetApplicationUniqueIdentifier(IServiceProvider) is supposed to work, but when I tried it the full path to the web root was returned.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6, the HostingEnvironment class has been replaced with the IHostEnvironment interface, and the ApplicationID property is no longer available. Instead, you can use the ApplicationName property of the IHostEnvironment interface to get an identifier for your application.

Here's an example of how you can retrieve the application name in a .NET 6 web service:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

```
// Inside your service or controller class

private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

public YourServiceOrController(IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
{
    _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
}

public void YourMethod()
{
    string applicationName = _hostEnvironment.ApplicationName;
    // Use the applicationName as needed
}
```

By using the ApplicationName property, you can retrieve an identifier that represents your application in a .NET 6 web service.